# highcharts: bubble-chart drilldown to donut-chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a bubble chart with a dynamic amount of bubbles, dependent on how many rows a user selects in a gridview.

A bubble in the chart represents a so called "system" which consists "products".

- Example 1: bubble "x" consists of 3 products "A", "B", "C".
- Example 2: bubble "y" consists of 2 products "D", "E".

Is it posible to fire the click event of a specific bubble to fire a donat drilldown with exact this additional information?

I simply want to change the chart type!
Click on a specific bubble -> changing the chart type to a single big donut in the same container -> "back-button" to get back to the bubbles again.

I only saw column-charts with pie-chart drilldown.

Has somebody a short and easy example in JSFiddle I can play with?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

In the drilled serie you need to define `type as pie`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uqthr1zb/